# Putting a value to a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I figured I would ask.  I am creating a spreadsheet and I want each cell to have a dollar value.  so for example b6 I want it to be worth $11.00 but I also just want to put a number in on how many are sold.  so B6 would have the number 1 for 1 meal sold but I need the value to be $11.00 for the total in AG6.  I hope this makes sense lol

Comment: No, this is not possible without using VBA. Complicated VBA at that. Welcome to SU, you might want to take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Without writing some rather horrific formulas or scripts, it's generally best to keep values that represent different types of data in separate cells.

For your example, which I presume is in reference to some sort of sales log, I'd suggest something like this:

- Sheet 1 is your sales log. Each line should have, at least:

  - A unique identifier (e.g.: UPC) for the product sold.
  - A short description of the product sold. (calculated by lookup).
  - The quantity of the product sold.
  - The individual sale price of the product (calculated by lookup).
  - The total sale price of the batch (calculated by multiplying individual price and quantity).
  - Any additional information (e.g.: date/time of sale, customer name, etc.) you want to track.
- Sheet 2 is your product database. You should have exactly one line per product that you sell. Each line should have, at least:

  - A unique identifier (e.g.: UPC) for the product.
  - A short description of the product. (This is what feeds the description in the log sheet.)
  - The individual sale price of the product. (This is what feeds the individual price in the log sheet.)
  - Any additional information (e.g.: quantity in stock, inventory cost, etc.) you want to track.
- Sheet 3 should be your summary sheet. This is where you pull in your totals and evaluate other general statistics. Nearly everything here should be formula-based.

  - This is where your current AG6 cell will go. The total should be calculated by doing a SUM of all the values in the "total sale price" column of Sheet 1.
  - Here, you can show more information of interest such as monthly sales, profits, etc.

Ideally though, really complex stuff like this is better handled in a database or purpose-built application.